Notion of "Hodge bundle" for abelian type Shimura varieties
For a Siegel type Shimura datum $(\text{GSp}_{2g}, \mathcal{H}^{\pm})$ and level $K$, we construct the Shimura variety $S_{g,K} := \text{Sh}_K(\text{GSp}_{2g},\mathcal{H}^{\pm})$. We have a universal abelian variety $\mathcal{A}_g \to S_{g,K}$, and we define the Hodge bundle $\omega_g$ by
$$\omega_g := \det\text{Fil}^1H_{dR}^1(\mathcal{A}_g/S_{g,K})$$
We can generalize this to the Hodge type case. Let $(G_1, X_1)$ be a Hodge type Shimura datum with embedding $\varphi : (G_1,X_1) \to (\text{GSp}_{2g}, \mathcal{H}^{\pm})$, meaning that $\varphi : G_1 \to \text{GSp}_{2g}$ is an injective homomorphism carrying $X_1$ into $\mathcal{H}^{\pm}$. Let $K_1$ be a compatible level so that we have a morphism $\varphi : Sh_{K_1}(G_1,X_1) \to S_{g,K}$. Then the Hodge bundle $\omega_1$ on $Sh_{K_1}(G_1,X_1)$ is given by $\omega_1 := \varphi^*\omega_g$.
The picture is less clear if we try to generalize to the abelian type case. Let $(G_2,X_2)$ be an abelian type Shimura datum, and let $(G_1, X_1)$ be an associated Hodge type datum, meaning there exists a central isogeny $\psi : G_1^{\text{der}} \to G_2^{\text{der}}$ which induces an isomorphism $(G_1^{\text{ad}},X_1^{\text{ad}}) \xrightarrow{\sim} (G_2^{\text{ad}},X_2^{\text{ad}})$ of adjoint data. One would want to transport the Hodge bundle $\omega_1$ from the Hodge type Shimura variety to the abelian type Shimura variety, but I don't immediately see how to do this.
My question is: is there some standard notion of Hodge bundle in the abelian type case? Or perhaps some other distinguished automorphic line bundle?
